# How to append all duplicate string names in a dictionary to make it a list of objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a key value pair of all duplicates fqdn with a list objects to its value pair.

This is a short example of what I want to achieve

```
data = [
    {
        "fqdn": "nytimes",
        "message": "success",
    },
    {
        "fqdn": "nytimes",
        "message": "error",
    }
]

collection = {}
for item in data:
    collection[item['fqdn']] = collection.get(item['fqdn'], item)
# Output : {'nytimes': {'fqdn': 'nytimes', 'message': 'success'}}
# Expected output: {'nytimes': [{'fqdn': 'nytimes', 'message': 'success'}, {'fqdn': 'nytimes', 'message': 'error'}]}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) for this.

```
collection = {}
for item in data:
    collection.setdefault(item['fqdn'], []).append(item)
```

**Output:**

```
{'nytimes': [{'fqdn': 'nytimes', 'message': 'success'}, {'fqdn': 'nytimes', 'message': 'error'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not quite right, it should look like this:

```
collection = {}
for item in data:
    collection[item['fqdn']] = collection.get(item['fqdn'], []) + [item]
```

Although, unless you have some data restrictions, I would recommend creating the empty space first and then appending to each space (as oppose to testing if each item already exists, creating an empty list, deleting the old list, and creating a new one):

```
collection = {item['fqdn']:[] for item in data}
for item in data:
    collection[item['fqdn']].append(item)
```